# Capture entry value in click event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a entry control added using c# to my xamarin.forms app. I also have a toolbaritem, on click of which I would like to save the data which is being entered by user.

I cannot access the text value in click event, I get this error:

`Error  20  The name 'txtTest' does not exist in the current context`

Here is my code sample:

```
public SettingsPage()
{

ToolbarItem Settings = new ToolbarItem();
Settings.Name = "Settings";
Settings.Clicked += OnClick_Settings;
Settings.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primaru;

ToolbarItems.Add(Settings);
loadData();
}

async public void loadData()
{
    Label lblTest = new Label { Text = "Test", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
    Entry txtTest = new Entry();

    StackLayout stLTest = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0),
        Children ={ 
            lblTest,
            txtTest
        }
    };  
    Content = stTest
}

async private void OnClick_Settings(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test= txtTest.Text;
}
```

In my `OnClick_Settings`,  I cannot find text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `txtTest` in `loadData()` method.
you should move it out of there.

Do this

```
Entry txtTest;    
async public void loadData()
{
    Label lblTest = new Label { Text = "Test", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
    txtTest = new Entry();

    StackLayout stLTest = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0),
        Children ={ 
            lblTest,
            txtTest
        }
    };  
    Content = stTest
}
```